# How is the evaluation of integer incrementation in chain of std::cout done?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Consider**

```
auto a = 0;
std::cout << a;
std::cout << a++;
std::cout << ++a;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

*Output:
    002*

Which is expected regarding the post and pre incrementation rule.

**However the following code**

```
auto a = 0;
std::cout << a << a++ << ++a << std::endl;
```

*Output: 
    212*

**Since the following seems to print number in the right order**

```
auto a = 0;
auto b = 1;
auto c = 2;
std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
```

*Output: 
    012*

I am trying to figure out why I got 212 in the second case?

Full code is here: https://ideone.com/IUiFb6

Comment: the second example is undefined behaviour. it's illegal to use the same self-modifying variable twice in the same statement

Comment: is it still UB in '17?

Comment: @xaxxon do you have a particular proposal in mind that would change it?

Comment: @user2079303 there *is* a proposal that defines order of evaluation rules. But I don't know if they affect this case.